# Clicking disabled button selects next element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This simple code creates a disabled button:

```
import { Grid, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import ArrowBackIosIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIos";

export default function App() {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item>Before</Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <IconButton disabled onClick={handleClick}>
            <ArrowBackIosIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>After</Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when clicking on the button the "After" div gets selected.
I have tried to prevent it by adding an event hanlder but it does not help.

How can I prevent "After" from being selected when clicking the enabled button?

here is my CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-elion-1tmtz0

Comment: What do you mean it gets selected? I tried adding `onSelect={...}` to the "After" grid item and it doesn't trigger...

Comment: Selected as in "doublclick to select". The background turns blue and you can Ctrl+C it.

Answer (score 0):

here is i made changes https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-paper-2ilsfh

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I need divs on both sides of the button.

Comment: You can add div using Styled mui , check i have updated code sandbox

Comment: Thank you for you effort but this is not the problem I am trying to solve. 1) the middle button has to be disabled; 2) in the 'after' div there is some text, not anothe button. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-burnell-6o5qfx